# Core plot Y axis labels don't show initially, but do subsequently

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

NB: This is different to the other question of a similar name.

My Y axis labels and their horizontal minor grid lines are not showing on initial, display, despite all their values being set. If I tap on some data points ( which triggers new data to be displayed) then the labels suddenly appear, and also appear for the old data set (initial).

I can't figure it out I've tried:

```
[graph display];
[y display];
```

I've grabbed the position of the y axis which is always on screen and is the same for the subsequent modes (when it display)

It just seems like a rendering bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed it, it wasn't a problem with the version of Core plot it was because the first draw of the graph was done in viewDidLoad, it needed to be in viewDidAppear

Answer (score 1):

This has likely been fixed since the 1.1 release. Pull the latest code with Mercurial and give it a try.

Comment: Are there any patches I can apply? I think I'm on 0.9

Comment: The 0.9 release went out over a year ago. There have been a lot of changes since then. It's hard to recommend a subset of the changes without knowing what issues you've encountered. It's probably simpler to just update to 1.1 or "latest" and fix the compatibility issues you've found. Check the [change log](http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/changelog.markdown) for info on the breaking changes.